# Truncate text without truncating HTML before_save call back

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This string has 78 characters with HTML and 39 characters without HTML:

```
<p>I really like the <a href="http://google.com">Google</a> search engine.</p>
```

I want to truncate this string based on the non-HTML character count, so for example if I wanted to truncate the above string to 24 characters, the output would be and this method is would be called as before_save callback:

```
<p>I really like the <a href="http://google.com">Google</a></p>
```

I tried multiple things i.e `truncate`, `html_safe` and `truncate with gsub` but I didn't get success every time I got this error.

```
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `truncate' for object
```

Here is my code:

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :truncate_description

  def truncate_description
    allowed_characters = self.is_special ? 600 : 400
    self.description = self.description.truncate(allowed_characters)
    #self.description = raw self.description.truncate(allowed_characters)
    #self.description = truncate(self.description, length: allowed_characters, omission: "" , escape: false)
    #self.description = truncate(self.description.gsub(/(<[^>]+>)/, ''), allowed_characters)
  end
end
```

I need my html string with specific character limit without breaking html and also don\t leave open HTML tags.

Comment: Could you show us what you tried? It could be helpful to see what code actually triggered that error message.

Comment: Also, what is it you're actually trying to do? This smells like a potential XY problem; you're giving an attempted solution, without really stating the original problem. For example, perhaps a better approach might be to truncate in the view - e.g. [using the `text-overflow` CSS property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp).

Comment: @TomLord I edited my question with my code that I tried actually and it's not working.

Comment: `self.description.truncate` returns a `NoMethodError`?? What is `self.description`?

Comment: Or did that error actually come from one of the commented out lines, like `truncate(self.description,.....)`? Please be clear what you mean by "not working".

Comment: Also... I just googled it, and [this gem was the top result](https://github.com/jorgemanrubia/truncato). Does that tool solve your problem?

Comment: @TomLord description is attribute column of model A. the commented lines means I tried these method as well

Comment: My complaint, Rana, is that you said "I tried multiple things" without showing any of them. Then you showed an error message, without showing what caused the error. Then you finally showed some code, but it presumably doesn't actually trigger the above error - because `self.description` is a **`String`**, and the `truncate` method *is* defined for a `String`.

Comment: Other potential solutions: [1](https://github.com/ianwhite/truncate_html) and [2](https://github.com/hgmnz/truncate_html).

Comment: @TomLord thank you so much truncato is working perfectly :)